# How do I get Flexslider2 to stop jumping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Flexslider2 (http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html)
and get this weird jumping effect within my project; Basically it cycles through and the frame collapses like in the image below. My linked .js files and the flex script are right before the closing body tag. Also no errors from chrome dev tools.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
<script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
       animation: "slide",
       start: function(slider){
       $('body').removeClass('loading');
       }
     });
     });
</script>
```

And this is the only piece of css I changed to fit my parameters. Any help would be swell!

```
.flexslider { margin: 0 auto 60px; max-width: 740px; background: #fff; border: 4px solid #fff; position: relative; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -o-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); zoom: 1; }
.flex-viewport { max-height: 2000px; max-width: 740px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; -o-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease; }
```

[image: Image of my problem]

Comment: APPARENTLY...I just realized 'liveReload' was causing the problem. Shut it down and no jumping. I didn't even realize i was using it cause i use codekit/guard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APPARENTLY...I just realized 'liveReload' was causing the problem. Shut it down and no jumping. I didn't even realize i was using it cause i use codekit/guard...